# FlutterBuilder doesn't show progressbar when future is updating;

Tags: flutter, dart

For the firs time when data is coming from server **FutureBuilder**, for some time return **CircularProgressIndicator** but when the future is updating i mean when updated data is coming from server till complication **FutureBuilder** shows pervious data. I want to show **CircularProgressBar** when new data is comming from server.

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet, so that we can help :)

Comment: If the `FutureBuilder` is hard to grasp, then I can recommend the ChangeNotifierProvider from the `provider` package. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifierprovider

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- You can maintain a state variable `loading` which will be true first.
- once data is loaded then set it to `false`. Do the same for update.
- Use ternary operator to return widget. Something like this.

  `loading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : YourWidget()`